# S3Client copyObject cross regiond

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to copy files between 2 S3 buckets on different regions:

> US_EAST_1  --->  EU_CENTRAL_1

Using the following command:

```
s3client.copyObject(sourceBucket, sourceFile, DestBucket, DestFile);
```

I initiate the s3client without providing a region to allow it to work with both regions, but I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The
>   bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the
>   specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
>   (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect;
>   Request ID: C2E6D084FF257437), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   rXDTuqPSCCKWoF8luScpL+/po93oEQC2VSNUBQtSLBh5q8yEAO0WwK8FnBMPGEZQjS+zwkkHWBg=
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1305)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:852)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:630)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:367)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:318)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3787)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1530)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1487)

I'm using 'aws-java-sdk' version: '1.11.7'

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The client cannot be configured to "work in both regions". It must be configured with a region so it works in a single region.

When copying objects between buckets (between regions), set the client to the *target* region. Then, specify the source and target buckets.

Comment: Thank you! That solved for me. I guess this is not clearly mentioned in AWS official document.